# Why am I getting error as function call returns immutable value in swiftui?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to play songs from albums between some time gaps and I used this code to achieve that concept. but I don't know why I'm getting this error. please help me to fix it.

```swift
mysongsplayer.play()
            
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
let starting_song = Double(now) + mysongsplayer.duration + (myModel.delay * 60)
            
let stop_song = starting_song + (myModel.time * 60)
while (start_song > stop_song) {
  for item in 0..<(selected_songs).count {
    if (stop_song > starting_song) {
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + starting_song) {
        selected_songs[item].play()
        Int(starting_song) += item + myModel.gap
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so at this point I'm getting this error

```
Int(starting_song) += item + myModel.gap
```

> Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: function call returns immutable value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1:** Thats because you when you type cast a value in swift, it returns an immutable value (read only). So statement `Int(starting_song)` will return a read only value, hence you can not change the value of it by adding `item` and `myModel.gap`.

**Issue 2:** Also you have declared `starting_song` as `let` so you cant change its value anyway.

First thing first, change `let starting_song`  to `var starting_song`.
Next change `Int(starting_song) += item + myModel.gap` to
`starting_song += Double(item + myModel.gap)`

This will work because 1. You are casting the sum of `item` and `gap` to double and the `starting_song` is already a double (type check will not fail) 2. The type casted value (sum of item and gap) is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that you need to reverse the cast to Int.

```
starting_song += Int(item + myModel.gap)
```